# Java Fork/Join for large inputs not finishing

Tags: java, forkjoinpool

I am trying to complete the coding for a parallel version of my sequential code of a 1D median filter on an input of float values. I have been using some smaller lengths of test values to code the parallel version and finally seemed to get the code working, however now on a large dataset of +-36000 elements the code seems to just ramp up CPU resources and not complete whereas my sequential version completes on the same given input. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Test input that works: 2, 6, 80, 3, 1 and produces correctly: 2,6,6,3,1

```
// median filter code
public class MedianFilter extends RecursiveAction {
    // filter class variables
    float[] numbers;
    int filter;
    int window;
    int length;
    int lo;
    int hi;
    // sequential cutoff set to predetermined value
    static final int SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF = 500;
    // array used for recursive calls in parallel code
    float[] filtered;

    float[] result;

    public MedianFilter(float[] numbers, int filter, int lo, int hi) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.filter = filter;
        this.lo = lo;
        this.hi = hi;
        length = numbers.length;
        // the section of floats to be filtered (median section)
        window = (filter - 1) / 2;
    }

    protected void compute() {
        filtered = new float[length];
        result = new float[length];

        if ((hi - lo) < SEQUENTIAL_CUTOFF) {
            for (int a = lo; a < hi; a++) {
                // iterate window through all elements of the array
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    // fetch boundary elements
                    if (i < window || i >= length - window) {
                        result[i] = numbers[i];
                    }
                    // fetch elements within filter window
                    else {
                        for (int j = 0; j < filter; j++) {
                            filtered[j] = numbers[i - window + j];
                        }
                        // order elements
                        for (int j = 0; j < filtered.length / 2; j++) {
                            // get the position of the smallest float
                            int min = j;
                            for (int k = j + 1; k < filter; k++) {
                                if (filtered[k] < filtered[min]) {
                                    min = k;
                                }
                                // reorder array for minimum element
                                float temp = filtered[j];
                                filtered[j] = filtered[min];
                                filtered[min] = temp;
                            }
                            // result
                            result[i] = filtered[window];
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        } else {

            MedianFilter left = new MedianFilter(filtered, filter, lo, (hi + lo) / 2);
            MedianFilter right = new MedianFilter(filtered, filter, (hi + lo) / 2, hi);
            left.fork();
            right.compute();
            left.join();
        }

    }
```

Comment: You're creating two full size (`length`) arrays per fork, meaning your memory consumption goes up exponentially. I suspect after enough forks, all your JVM does is trying (and failing) to collect garbage.

Comment: Thanks @biziclop I have removed those lines (creating new floats[length] within the method) but i still yield the same result...